# HtmlHelper implementation MVC 6 vNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm working with ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6.  I am using a custom HtmlHelper inside of a partial page to register a script tag with the HttpContext so that I can delay rendering the script tag until the end of the page.

This code registers the script tag:

```
    public static HtmlString AddResource(this IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper, PageResourceType resourceType, Func<object, HelperResult> Template)
    {     
            if (HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] != null)
            {
                ((List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[resourceType]).Add(Template);
            }
            else
            {
                HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] = new List<Func<object, HelperResult>>() { Template };
            }

           return new HtmlString(String.Empty);
    }
```

The usage for registering a script tag from a Razor page using this helper is

```
 @Html.AddResource(PageResourceType.JavaScript ,
                    @<script src='~/js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js'></script>
                    )
```

This code, called from _Layout.cshtml, renders any registered script tags:

```
    public static HtmlString RenderResources(this IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper, PageResourceType resourceType)
    {
        if (HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] != null)
        {
            List<Func<object, HelperResult>> Resources = (List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[resourceType];

            foreach (var Resource in Resources)
            {
                if (Resource != null)
                {
                    HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(Resource(null));
                }
            }
        }

        return new HtmlString(String.Empty);
    }
```

Those two bits work nicely, however, I now have an additional HtmlHelper that I want to use to create a particular UI element (Sparkline UI widget, in this case) that relies on a script tag.

```
    public static HtmlString Sparkline(this IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper, IEnumerable<int> values, string cssClasses)
    {            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<div class='sparkline txt-color-blue hidden-mobile hidden-md hidden-sm'>");
        sb.Append(string.Join(",", values));
        sb.Append("</div>");

        HtmlHelper.AddResource(PageResourceType.JavaScript, (x) =>
        {
            return new HelperResult(writer =>
            {
                string script = "<script src='~/js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js'></script>";
                return new Task(() => writer.Write(script));
            });
        });

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Notice, that it makes a call to the previous register method via

```
HtmlHelper.AddResource
```

The problem is that when the RenderResources code executes, the app just hangs indefinitely.  I had this working under the old MVC 5 system, but had to make some changes to account for new MVC 6 constructs (Tag Helpers is what caused the change I think), and I bungled it somehow.

Any idea how to properly implement the Sparkline method, particularly the call to HtmlHelper.AddResource?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the minute I post the question, I find the answer.  Although, I'm not sure why it fixes the problem, since I assumed that wrapping the .Write method inside of a Task would be the same as calling .WriteAsync ...

```
    HtmlHelper.AddResource(PageResourceType.JavaScript, (x) =>
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            string script = "<script src='~/js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js'></script>";
            return new Task(() => writer.Write(script));
        });
    });
```

should be

```
    HtmlHelper.AddResource(PageResourceType.JavaScript, (x) =>
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            string script = "<script src='~/js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js'></script>";
            return writer.WriteAsync(script);
        });
    });
```